# argparse multiple optional arguments

Tags: python

I'm writing a script which searches for a regex in one or more input files. If no input file is provided (or there is an `"-"` instead of a file), it should search in `stdin`.

Example: `myscript.py [-h] [-u | -c | -m] [infile [infile ...]] regex`

What I don't understand is - how does it differentiate filename from regex?
Let's say I type in `myscript.py file1 file2 regex`. How does it know that `regex` is a regular expression and not another file?

My code is as below:

```
def init_parser():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="The script searches one or more named input files for lines\
     containing a match to a regular expression pattern."
  )
  parser.add_argument(
    '-f','--infile', nargs='*', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default='-',
    help='the name of the file(s) to search.'
  )
  parser.add_argument('regex', help='the regular expression.')
  group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
  group.add_argument(
    '-u', '--underscore', action='store_true', 
    help='prints "^" under the matching text.'
  )
  group.add_argument(
    '-c', '--color', action='store_true', 
    help='highlights matching text.'
  )
  group.add_argument(
    '-m', '--machine', action='store_true', 
    help='generates machine readable output.'
  )

  return parser
```

Since there are no flags to specify  the regex, the script can't differentiate between files and regex. If I don't specify a file (because I want it to read from `stdin`) it thinks that my regex is a file and it fails.

Comment: You've answered your own question in the last part thereof: "Since there are no flags to specify  the regex, the script can't differentiate between files and regex." To fix this, add a flag/argument specification for the regex *before* the files: `myscript.py -r regex [-h] [-u | -c | -m] [infile [infile ...]]`

Comment: OR put the regex first (presumably it is always specified) then infile can take the rest of the positional arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will always have a regex on the commandline, if you put the regex argument first, then infile, this will take the other positional arguments you specify:

```
parser.add_argument('regex', help='the regular expression.')
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='*', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='the name of the file(s) to search.')
```